# Corrupt video when playing through JW Player

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have some files that when played in jwplayer the playback is corrupt.
The files are encoded to h.264 using FFMpeg and there is other files encoded in the same way that works.

At the moment we only use the flash version of the player.

The corrupt playback looks like this:

http://adam.ingmansson.com/public/jwplayer-corrupt-video.png

This problem started showing up after we did an upgrade to FFMpeg, so I haven't ruled out that it could be an encoding error.

the command used to run FFMpeg is:

```
ffmpeg 
    -i /home/ftp/1c8f08b7d0d9e7fa4b24066156ad50bc981497a0.mov 
    -vcodec libx264 
    -preset ultrafast 
    -profile baseline 
    -acodec libfaac 
    -ab 96k 
    -crf 19 
    -vf movie="/home/adam/logo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" 
    -y /home/ftp/1c8f08b7d0d9e7fa4b24066156ad50bc981497a0.flv
```

I am in no way an expert in FFMpeg commandline, so feel free to point out any mistakes made.

FFMpeg info:

```
ffmpeg version git-2012-05-02-2330eb1 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May  3 2012 08:51:25 with gcc 4.4.3
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      51. 49.100 / 51. 49.100
  libavcodec     54. 17.101 / 54. 17.101
  libavformat    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 72.103 /  2. 72.103
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 11.100 /  0. 11.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/ftp/javarecorder/aeb1038bd3e380782e2293cfdeb56ba8fab0d167.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2012-05-15 16:33:35
  Duration: 00:25:01.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4299 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: qtrle (rle  / 0x20656C72), rgb24, 1920x1080, 3593 kb/s, 9.24 fps, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-05-15 16:33:35
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-05-15 16:33:35
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the framerate was the problem. JW Player seems to have problems playing videos with high framerates (like 1k).

A simple `-r 30` in the FFMpeg command seems to have solved it

Comment: Did the movie have a frame rate of 1 000 frames per second??